# JAVA -Debo crear un método que calcule la edad . La fecha de nacimiento se recibe a través de unTextField como String, en formato DD-MM-YYY

Tags: java

Tengo que implementar un método que calcule la edad de un paciente. La fecha de nacimiento proviene de un TextField, como String y está en formato DD-MM-YYYY.
El resultado tengo que pasarlo como un parámetro int a otro método.
He intentado hacerlo de un montón de maneras posibles y siempre encuentro problemas a la hora de convertir la fecha de String a int.

/**
* Calcula y muestra la edad
*/

```
public void calcularEdad()
{   
    
    String fechaNacimiento = sistemaPacientes.darPacienteActual().darFechaNacimiento(); //fecha en formato DD-MM-YYY
    Calendar fechaActual = new GregorianCalendar();
                                                
    int añoActual = fechaActual.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int mesActual = fechaActual.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int diaActual = fechaActual.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    
    StringBuffer dia = new StringBuffer();
    StringBuffer mes = new StringBuffer();
    StringBuffer año = new StringBuffer();
    String[] strArray = new String[] {fechaNacimiento};
    for (int i=0; i < 2; i++)
        dia = dia.append(strArray[i]);
    for (int i=3; i < 5; i++)
        mes = mes.append(strArray[i]);
    for (int i=6; i < 10; i++)
        año = año.append(strArray[i]);
    
    String diaNac = dia.toString();
    String mesNac = mes.toString();
    String añoNac = año.toString();
    int edad = 0;
    int iDiaNac = Integer.valueOf(diaNac); 
    int iMesNac = Integer.valueOf(mesNac);
    int iAñoNac = Integer.valueOf(añoNac);
    
    if (mesActual > iMesNac)
        edad = añoActual - iAñoNac;
    else if (mesActual == iMesNac && diaActual >= iDiaNac)
        edad =añoActual - iAñoNac;
    else 
        edad = añoActual - iAñoNac - 1;
    panelDatosPaciente.mostrarEdad(edad);
    
}
```

Comment: `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) y *parsear* la fecha con un [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) al formato que tengas (lee la sección de [***Patterns for Formatting and Parsing***](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html)) . En este caso deberías usar:

1. "dd": Días en dos dígitos
2. "MM": Meses en dos dígitos
3. "YYYY": Año en cuatro dígitos

Para calcular la diferencia entre dos días puedes hacerlo con [`ChronoUnit`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html) o lo puedes hacer con [`Period`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Period.html)

Te dejo un ejemplo, el cual trabaja con todo lo anterior conjuntado

```java
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.Period;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;
import java.util.Locale;

public class DateCalculator {
    protected void sayMyAge(String date){

        LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
        LocalDate birth = LocalDate.parse(date, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy", Locale.getDefault()));

        Period my_age = birth.until(today);

        System.out.printf("%s %d %s %d %s %d %s\n",
                "Tengo",
                my_age.getYears(),
                "años,",
                my_age.getMonths(),
                "meses,",
                my_age.getDays(),
                "días"
        );

        System.out.printf("\n%s %d %s\n", "Tengo", ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(birth, today), "días");
        System.out.printf("%s %d %s\n", "Tengo", ChronoUnit.MONTHS.between(birth, today), "meses");
        System.out.printf("%s %d %s\n", "Tengo", ChronoUnit.YEARS.between(birth, today), "años");
    }
}
```

Y los outputs esperados para **05-01-2005** serían:

```
// Con Period
Tengo 16 años, 4 meses, 2 días

//Con ChronoUnit
Tengo 5966 días
Tengo 196 meses
Tengo 16 años
```

**EDIT:**

Ya que el String que recibe puede ser inválido, te recomendaría añadir un
[`throws DateTimeException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/DateTimeException.html) al método y cuando necesite ser invocado utilizar try-catch

Answer (score 2):

Usa `java.time.LocalDate`

Tiene un método estático `LocalDate.parse(CharSequence, DateTimeFormatter)` que encaja con lo que buscas.
Por ejemplo:

```
LocalDate miFecha= LocalDate.parse("07-05-2021", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy"));
```

El día actual lo obtienes con `LocalDate.now()`

Además, puedes calcular fácilmente la edad con objetos `LocalDate` usando `java.time.Duration.between(localDate1, localDate2).get(ChronoUnit.YEARS)`

Answer (score 0):

Puedes convertir fácilmente a fecha con la clase `SimpleDateFormat`, ejemplo:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;  
import java.util.Date;  
...
    String sFecha = "07-05-2019";  
    Date fecha = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").parse(sFecha);
```